# Get coordinates of white pixels (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, threshold

In OpenCV (C++) I have a b&w image where some shapes appear filled with white (255). Knowing this, how can I get the coordinate points in the image where theses objects are? I'm interested on getting all the white pixels coordinates.

Is there a cleaner way than this?

```
std::vector<int> coordinates_white; // will temporaly store the coordinates where "white" is found 
for (int i = 0; i<img_size.height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<img_size.width; j++) {
        if (img_tmp.at<int>(i,j)>250) {
            coordinates_white.push_back(i);
            coordinates_white.push_back(j);
        }
    }
}
// copy the coordinates into a matrix where each row represents a *(x,y)* pair
cv::Mat coordinates = cv::Mat(coordinates_white.size()/2,2,CV_32S,&coordinates_white.front());
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

there is a built-in function to do that [cv::findNonZero](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190&gsc.tab=0)

Returns the list of locations of non-zero pixels.

Given a binary matrix (likely returned from an operation such as `cv::threshold()`, `cv::compare()`, `>`, `==`, etc) returns all of the non-zero indices as a `cv::Mat` or `std::vector<cv::Point>`

For example:

```
cv::Mat binaryImage; // input, binary image
cv::Mat locations;   // output, locations of non-zero pixels
cv::findNonZero(binaryImage, locations);
// access pixel coordinates
Point pnt = locations.at<Point>(i);
```

or

```
cv::Mat binaryImage; // input, binary image
vector<Point> locations;   // output, locations of non-zero pixels
cv::findNonZero(binaryImage, locations);
// access pixel coordinates
Point pnt = locations[i];
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use this method to get the white pixels.. hope it will help u.

```
 for(int i = 0 ;i <image.rows() ; i++){// image:the binary image
                for(int j = 0; j< image.cols() ; j++){
                    double[] returned = image.get(i,j); 
                    int value = (int) returned[0]; 
                    if(value==255){
                    System.out.println("x: " +i + "\ty: "+j);//(x,y) coordinates
                    }
                }

            }
```